# SVN error on connecting with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, subclipse, javahl

When I am trying to connect SVN to eclipse I am getting the following error: any idea how to resolve it?

```
Failed to load JavaHL Library.
These are the errors that were encountered:
no libapr-1 in java.library.path
no libapriconv-1 in java.library.path
C:\Program Files (x86)\Subversion\bin\libeay32.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
C:\Program Files (x86)\Subversion\bin\ssleay32.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
no libaprutil-1 in java.library.path
C:\Program Files (x86)\TortoiseSVN\bin\libsasl.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
no libsvn_subr-1 in java.library.path
no libsvn_delta-1 in java.library.path
no libsvn_diff-1 in java.library.path
no libsvn_wc-1 in java.library.path
no libsvn_fs-1 in java.library.path
no libsvn_repos-1 in java.library.path
no libsvn_ra-1 in java.library.path
no libsvn_client-1 in java.library.path
no libsvnjavahl-1 in java.library.path
no svnjavahl-1 in java.library.path
no svnjavahl in java.library.path
java.library.path = C:\Windows\system32;.;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\JavaFX\javafx-sdk1.3\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\JavaFX\javafx-sdk1.3\emulator\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\OTG;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program Files\Intel\DMIX;C:\Program Files\Dell\DW WLAN Card;c:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;c:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Subversion\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics AX\60\BusinessConnector\Bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics AX\60\Client\Bin\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics AX\60\ManagementUtilities
```

Comment: There is 64 bit JavaHL support in SilkSVN

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
window -> preferences -> team -> svn
```

Choose SVN Interface:

client : SVNKit (Pure Java)

Apply and try again.

Comment: I have similar problem but I only have JavaHL client. How did you install the SVNKit (Pure Java)?

Comment: search subclipse plugin for eclipse and install it from eclipse update link. it should be installed automatically

Comment: Same process on the Mac using Flash Builder 4.6 -- worked great, thanks for the tip.  I was resurrecting an old Flex/Flash Builder project and I had the same thing.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

This is for Windows: (for linux you're going to have to do something a little bit different, sorry):

If you have a

- 64bit machine
- 64bit eclipse
- 64bit jvm

just do the following, to enjoy the stability and performance of native JavaHL:

1. Download and install the newest 64bit version of [SlikSvn](http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download/) (Note, that it is downwards compatible)
2. add the following line to your eclipse.ini, it should point to the correct libsvnjavahl-1.dll:

   `-Dsubversion.native.library=C:/Program Files/SlikSvn/bin/libsvnjavahl-1.dll`

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the Eclipse interface to SVN so that it does not use JavaHL. Here's what I did:

Preferences/Team/SVN/SVN interface

* unchecked JavaHL (JNI) Not Available

* checked SVNKit (Pure Java)

After that it never complained about JavaHL libraries.