# JavaHL Library not found error

Tags: eclipse, svn, flex4, flexbuilder

I installed SVN using the instruction give here: http://alvijee.blogspot.com/2010/08/setting-up-subversion-with-adobe-flash.html
I did select JavaHL Native Library while installation are restarted Flex Builder too.

Now, from Window > Perspective > Other > SVN Repository Exploring, if I try to checkout a repository following error pops up:

```
Failed to load JavaHL Library.
These are the errors that were encountered:
no libapr-1 in java.library.path
no libapriconv-1 in java.library.path
no libeay32 in java.library.path
no ssleay32 in java.library.path
no libaprutil-1 in java.library.path
C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\libsasl.dll: Can't load AMD 64-bit .dll on a IA 32-bit platform
no libsvn_subr-1 in java.library.path
no libsvn_delta-1 in java.library.path
no libsvn_diff-1 in java.library.path
no libsvn_wc-1 in java.library.path
no libsvn_fs-1 in java.library.path
no libsvn_repos-1 in java.library.path
no libsvn_ra-1 in java.library.path
no libsvn_client-1 in java.library.path
no libsvnjavahl-1 in java.library.path
no svnjavahl-1 in java.library.path
no svnjavahl in java.library.path
java.library.path = C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4;.;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files (x86)/Adobe/Adobe Flash Builder 4/jre/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Adobe/Adobe Flash Builder 4/jre/bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.7\miktex\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;c:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files\Dell\Dell Wireless WLAN Card;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin
```

Has anybody solved this problem on Windows. I have searched for a solution but people have got such problems on Linux machine. Couldn't find a solution for Flex Builder running in Windows. Has anyone encountered this error?

Comment: Could you add eclipse version (32 vs 64bit) and distro you are using? Depending on the version, the delivery of JavaHL will be different. Have a look at [SVN error on conecting with eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721456/svn-error-on-conecting-with-eclipse), problem seems similar. Has to do with Java 64bit ...

Comment: I am using 32 bit eclipse. Thanks for the pointer but I don't have  SVNKit (Pure Java) client interface available. The only interface I have is "JavaHL (JNI) Not Available".

Comment: SVNKit Library is however, installed as seen from Available Softwares window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to mliebelt for directing me in the right direction. I was using 32-bit eclipse but had tortoise 64 bit installed and SVN+SSH environment variable was set to
C:\Program Files (x86)\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoisePlink.exe. I just uninstalled Tortoise 64bit and installed its 32 bit version. The problem has now went away. :)

Comment: Fine, so it is due to a problem of the native JavaHL library on Windows, 32bit vs. 64bit. I have installed on my Windows 7 PC both TortoiseSVN 32bit and TortoiseSVN 64bit, that is possible as well.